# How to calculate the weight of Two-Stage Weighted Least Squares Estimation to slove heteroskidasticity?

Tags: r, glm

I am analysing a dataset by using glm(). The residual plot shows evident heteroskidasticity(see this [link](https://github.com/MarkHsiehthelearner/The-Hive/blob/master/residual%20plot_2.jpeg)).

I am trying to solve it via Two-stage wls(weighted least square) regression, but the residual plot still shows inconstant various. The problem might be I didn't get the weight correctly.

```
model_1 <- glm(log(Y) ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7, 
                      data = train, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
w = 1/(model_1$residuals)^2
glm_wls <- glm(log(Y) ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7, 
                data = train, family = gaussian(link = "log"), 
                weights = w)
```

I am expecting that the glm_wls model could slove the problem, but I don't think I got the right w.